# Problemas com composer, mcrypt e laravel no ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, composer, mcrypt

Já tenho um projeto preexistente e preciso instalar nele o laravel, porém dá isso:

```
$ php ../composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.11)



  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                 
  Project directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/balaozinho/src/laravel/ is not empty.  



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: não poderia excluir o conteúdo dentro do folder existente ou movê-lo para outro local como backup?

Comment: Qual  é o problema com `mcrypt`?

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que o diretório "laravel" já existe. Crie um projeto definindo um outro nome. Por exemplo:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

Troque "your-project-name" pelo nome do diretório

Sobre o Mcrypt, você precisa insltalar a lib mcrypt (a lib em si e a lib pro PHP):

```
apt-get install libmcrypt4 php5-mcrypt
```

Um artigo completíssimo sobre Composer pode ser visto aqui:
http://rberaldo.com.br/composer-php/